# Weird mouse behaviour

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, mouse, taskbar

Recently I have encountered a problem with my mouse:

- Sometimes I can't click normally but sometimes I can,
- My mouse only worked inb some specific parts of the screen. For example:

  - When I open a browser located on desktop (eg Google Chrome) I was able to click on the address, close tabs, etc
  - When I click on Window/taskbar or Right-click the taskbar, it just doesn't work.
- When I am finally able to click on Window/taskbar, I can't use my mouse on the desktop or open any software that is located on the desktop.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you fed your mouse lately....  ;-)...if you have mouse software installed try reinstalling it.

Comment: How often are you experiencing these problems?  Is this happening regularly, or were these just one time occurrences?  What make/model/type of mouse is in question?  Does it have the same problems while Windows is booted into Safe Mode?  Does the mouse behave OK while attached to another computer?  If it's wireless, did you try fresh batteries?  Relocating the receiver?

Comment: While problems are in effect, could you try connecting another mouse and check whether you see the same problems also with second mouse?

Comment: The mouse is death adder 2013. Only recently I experience this problem, and yes, I encouter this problem all the time. I tried to uninstall and reinstall the mouse, update driver, still not work.

Comment: I also try to connect another mouse too, and it also have same problem. Also, I tried to connect this mouse (deathadder) to my laptop and it worked perfectly @@

Answer (score 0):

**Universal Mouse Troubleshooting Guide**

1) Restarts can do wonders. Save your work and try a restart.

2) If it is a wireless one, try changing the batteries. Apple magic mouse battery level is shown in the mac.

3) Make sure the issue is with YOUR mouse. Plug in another mouse and check for the same issues. If the other one works fine, you-know-what change the mouse.

4) Wait! before you discard your old one, check it in another pc and check whether it works. if it does, keep the mouse. There was something wrong with drivers or the connection in your PC.

5)If you have any mouse-related software, uninstall them. (which you won't need, they are optional even for touch pads; unless you do very specific work with your mouse).

6) Restart again.

7) If all till 6) fails buy a new cheap one until you discard or fix your old one. They are quite cheap and can be bought without crowdfunding help.

8) If you still want to persist with your old mouse,  check everything from 1) again and this time check receivers, dust and do everything  you can find on  google.

9) Do 8) until you get tired and move onto your new mouse.

*10) NEVER EVER commit suicide over a mouse.*